# Will Symfony2 Security Component Work With A Multi-Domained System?

Tags: php, symfony, acl, symfony-2.1

We are working on a hosted CMS system that will serve multiple domains from the same database and codebase. We are building it with Symfony2, we have an idea on how to get the multiple domains working with dynamic hosts but I wonder if the Security Component would work with multiple domains and recognize different domain logins and sessions. Also how the Admins and Superadmins would login and work on managing all domains? For users I can save the domain or sitename with the user in the database but how will we get that into the session that the Security Component handles on it's own.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes, this should be possible– you may need to write a custom handler of some kind to synchronise the sessions using something not too dissimilar to the normal techniques you would use to achieve this in PHP.

You may find that you need to use a relatively recent release, 2.2 perhaps, I think this includes some stuff for multi-domain routing- which may be an issue.

With regards to admin/superadmin capabilities, assuming the above all should work as expected, just ensure all of your firewalls (if you have >1) operate on the same context, otherwise they will need to re-authenticate for each firewall.